# How to do a transition effect in android while clicking a button, the button has to grow bigger as the screen size

Tags: android, android-studio

In android How to do a transition effect while clicking a button, then the button should grow bigger and match the screen size and launch another activity.

[transition example GIF](https://assets.materialup.com/uploads/5a881f99-9d15-4acf-8077-e68f12c0e2d8/todo_login.gif)

like how the sign in button animates in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Refer this links :

1. [Trasnsition Animation For Activities](http://lgvalle.xyz/2015/06/07/material-animations/)
2. [Transition Animation](https://medium.com/@andkulikov/animate-all-the-things-transitions-in-android-914af5477d50)

This are basically two different activities with shared Animation element.

Comment: thank you so much i had tried second link already but first link gives me the exact result as i wish.